# How to retrieve all the elements name from a xml schema

Tags: java, parsing, schema, element

I am having a problem with getting a name of a schema elements in java. I am creating a small xml editor which can load a xml schema and validate a xml file against xml schema. I want to parse a schema, get every elements name and then put it in my content assistant, so the user can see all the available elements.

I already read XSOM User's guide, but I didn't understand much...

Can someone help me to implement my addElementsFromSchema(File xsdfile) function, because I lost myself trying.

```
public static void addElementsFromSchema(File xsdfile){

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all `<xsd:element>` definitions?  Do you only want the names (as defined in each <xsd:element name="…">), or do you need each element's entire type definition?

Comment: I must get for each element's entire type definition. But, in the content assistant will be shown only the name (name="...").

Comment: Do you know how you will visually represent each element's definition?  Do you want to display the original XML, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: When the schema is loaded and when a user starts to write a xml and he press '<', the content assistant appears with all the available elements retrieved from a schema. This is why I need to parse a schema.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your primary need, at least for now, is to get the element names.  You can get the element names with something like:

```
XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();
parser.parse(xsdfile);

XSSchemaSet schemas = parser.getResult();
Iterator<XSElementDecl> i = schemas.iterateElementDecls();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    XSElementDecl element = i.next();
    String name = element.getName();
    // Add to editor
}
```

Showing element *definitions* is a lot more difficult, as element declarations in XML schemas can get quite complex.

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting a lot of errors: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/relaxng/datatype/ValidationContext Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext

Comment: You need relaxngDatatype.jar in your classpath. From http://xsom.java.net : **Both flavors of xsom.jar depends on relaxngDatatype.jar and JAXP 1.1. Make sure you have at least xsom.jar and relaxngDatatype.jar when you distribute your application that uses XSOM.**